# Selecting a row in excel based on specific values in 2 columns,

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Data roughly in the format

```
A    B    C
ID1  ID2  0.5
ID1  ID3  0.7
ID2  ID3  0.9
```

I want to create a correlation matrix (column C being the correlation between the IDs in A and B).  It can definitely be done with a pivot table, though I have to use sum which could be risky if a duplicate existed since an error might not be apparent.  Output format would be:

```
    ID1 ID2 ID3
ID1  1  .5  .7
ID2 .5   1  .9
ID3 .7  .9   1
```

(the '1' is easily done with an `=IF(B$2=$A3,1,0)` and replacing 0 with the formula to find the correlation)

I basically want a match (`col a= ID1` && `col b = ID2`).  I suspect it could be done by concatenation, but I am not sure that is a great solution?  Match/Vlookup etc only return the first match [in that column], which is no good to me. Ode to a 'where' clause I guess?

My searches did not reveal any usuable help, I have already calculated the correlation and am putting it into excel from SQL.  So yeah, any ideas would be super, a pivot table being a last resort.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your source data range is on Sheet1, from A1 to C3 and your results range is on Sheet2, from A1 to D4.

You can put this formula on B2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3=Sheet2!B$1)*(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3=Sheet2!$A2)*Sheet1!$C$1:$C$3)
```

and then, drag and drop this formula on the whole range.

Comment: You could also use a similar version but with LOOKUP, that has the advantage that column C can be text or number, i.e. `=LOOKUP(2,1/(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3=Sheet2!B$1)/(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3=Sheet2!$A2),Sheet1!$C$1:$C$3)`

Comment: @barryhoudini: interesting solution too. This is probably worth an answer :)

Comment: Barry, the lookup version does not appear to work, i am getting an error in excel.  The values will always be numbers - but sumproduct runs the same risk as a pivot table where duplicate data would result in the kickout of wrong information - but not obviously wrong. 

 Either way it is a brilliant solution, so thank you Jmax.  I did not realise you could use that sort of logical indexing in Excel.

Comment: Glad it helped. I can't see any easy way to check for dupes in the very same formula. Yet, you could add another formula to specifically check for dupes in another column if you really need to :)

Comment: As an aside the LOOKUP formula now works, but only when I delete and then manually input " Sheet1!$C$2:$C$4 "
 Have no idea why.  I am also slightly perplexed by the 2 which seems to have no impact on the formula. Problem well solved though.

Comment: The way the formula works the "lookup array" is formed by 1/(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3=Sheet2!B$1)/(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3=Sheet2!$A2) and will consist of 1s and errors only. The lookup value just needs to be a number > any number in that array, so 2 is the convention, but it would work with 13 or 1000....just don't use 1 or a lower number...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a third column that combines the values from columns `A` and `B` using `=A1&B1` and then do `vlookup` on that value:

```
A    B    C       D
ID1  ID2  ID1ID2  0.5
ID1  ID3  ID1ID3  0.7
ID2  ID3  ID2ID3  0.9
```