# Match function to match multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I have two columns

```
Column A   Column B 
Apple       A
banana      B
Grape       C
Apple       D
Banana      F
```

Now I want to find the row number for row which has data `Apple` & `D`.

Is their a way to use `Match` function to get the row number?

Comment: This is a duplicate of both [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307976/find-the-number-of-a-row-that-contains-two-specific-values) AND [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110429/selecting-a-row-in-excel-based-on-specific-values-in-2-columns)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A5="Apple")/(B1:B5="D"),ROW(A1:A5))
```

or non-volatile version (if your ranges starts from first row):

```
=MATCH(2,1/(A1:A5="Apple")/(B1:B5="D"))
```

with array entry (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

Alternate, does not require array entry:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A1:A5&B1:B5="Apple"&"D",),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this !!

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MATCH(1,(A1:A5="Apple")*(B1:B5="D"),0)))
```

Array formula CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER